# override specific DN fields when signing csr

Tags: openssl, certificate-authority, pki, csr

When signing CSR on CA side, how can I override specific DN fields by custom value?
I want to ignore what is written in CSR. For example in *C=* and *O=* fields and replace them by something static. Other values, like *CN=*, should be accepted from CSR.

*openssl/ca/policy* configuration only supports *match* and *supplied* options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a way to override a field from the CSR using the OpenSSL configuration file. The configuration file can only supply default values. There are two options that I can see:

1. If you're using the `openssl ca` command to sign a CSR, you can override the subject from the CSR using the `-subject` argument. So, get the subject from the CSR (`openssl req -noout -subject -in req.pem`), search-and-replace the fields you want to change, and specify the altered subject on the command line with `-subject`.
2. If the static fields that you want are always going to have the same value, you could build your CA certificate so that your policy configuration can specify `match` for the static fields, i.e. your CA certificate contains the static values in its own fields (e.g. `O`, `OU`).

Comment: Thanks for 1), it didn't came to my mind. I want to fill in the fields from some database. Your tip can be used to do that.